# Continously updating a single plt.figure instead of creating multiple figure-windows

Tags: python, matplotlib, figure

Ive got a loop in which i gather measurement data which needs to be drawn in about 12 subplots (here only 4 subplots) in 1 figure, which should update the subplots during every loop-cycle. 
However, my code just creates an additional figure-window every loop-cycle instead of updating the single figure-window. 
Also the measurement data consists of large float-values (e.g. 989.9871234) which crowds my major y-tick labels, so the y-axis are unreadable and i havent found a working solution to limit the number of y-axis-labels.
I used the example from [Code example](https://www.python-course.eu/matplotlib_multiple_figures.php) as the basis for my code.

Heres my code (unnecessary measurement data gathering omitted):

```
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 4))
    sub1 = fig.add_subplot(221)
    sub1.plot(secondspassed_array, resistance1_array)
    sub2 = fig.add_subplot(222)
    sub2.plot(secondspassed_array, resistance2_array)
    sub3 = fig.add_subplot(223)
    sub3.plot(secondspassed_array, resistance3_array)
    sub4 = fig.add_subplot(224)
    sub4.plot(secondspassed_array, resistance4_array)
    plt.plot(secondspassed_array, resistance4_array)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.ion()
    plt.pause(0.05)
```

Comment: why are you plotting and subplotting the same data? is that a copy/paste error? See `sub4.plot` and `plt.plot` calls

Comment: Please read and understand [mcve]. Of course you need to create the subplots outside the loop which updates the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to put `plt.figure(figsize=(6, 4))` outside the loop